# Possible bug in Xcode/iOS simulator cannot control size of UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, ios-simulator

iOS Simulator 8.4
Xcode 6.4

The below code creates a new view controller with height of 5 correctly only in the 4s simulator and my iPad 2.

Every other simulator above 4s it creates a `ViewController` with a height that looks to be about 150 pixels high.

I have auto layout and size classes disabled.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad()  {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let itemvc = UIViewController()
        itemvc.view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        itemvc.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        itemvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 5)

        self.addChildViewController(itemvc)
        self.view.addSubview(itemvc.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: submit this to apple and win the award mate!

Comment: may i ask why you are making a view controller inside another view controller?

Comment: I found a hack that works. Set up a timer that changes the size 0.1 second later.

Comment: Also found that moving the create function to the viewDidLayoutSubviews function will work. This is a problem that happens when size classes are turned on. In my project they are turned off. Perhaps the bug is caused by the Simulator thinking size classes are on even though they are off.